# Using AWK command to skip first line and determine if a '/' is in specific column which happens to be a date in a CSV file

Tags: shell, awk

Using AWK command to skip first line and determine if a '/' is in specific column  which happens to be a date in a CSV file, although for my request the Date field must only be formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD' no Slashes

this is what I have so far but I can't get it to recognize the Slashes in the Date field (Column 11) in the File and treat it as invalid and print the Record out.

I am not a experienced Script script writer, Please help :-)

```
awk -F \| '{if(NR > 1) {{$11~/[/]/}}}' $datadir/sys_slate_app_test.csv > "invalid_other.txt"


   awk: fatal: cannot open file `/sys_slate_app_test.csv' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

```
awk -F \| '{if(NR > 1) {{$11~/^//}}}' $datadir/sys_slate_app_test.csv > "invalid_other.txt"

   awk: cmd. line:1: {if(NR > 1) {{$11~/^//}}}
   awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ syntax error
```

data:

```
"30"|"958433018"|"999999999"|"11111111"|"202340"|""|"222222222"|"Tyler"|"Ward"|"email328@yahoo.com"|"2022/08/23"|"UG"|"TR"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"2"|"1"|"RD"|"0"|"1"|"2023-03-09"
"30"|"958433018"|"999999999"|"11111111"|"202340"|""|"222222222"|"Tyler"|"Ward"|"email328@yahoo.com"|"2022/09/10"|"UG"|"TR"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"2"|"1"|"RD"|"0"|"1"|"2023-03-09"
"30"|"958433018"|"999999999"|"11111111"|"202340"|""|"222222222"|"Tyler"|"Ward"|"email328@yahoo.com"|"2022-08-23"|"UG"|"TR"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"2"|"1"|"RD"|"0"|"1"|"2023-03-09"
"30"|"958433018"|"999999999"|"11111111"|"202340"|""|"222222222"|"Tyler"|"Ward"|"email328@yahoo.com"|"2022-06-11"|"UG"|"TR"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"2"|"1"|"RD"|"0"|"1"|"2023-03-09"
"30"|"958433018"|"999999999"|"11111111"|"202340"|""|"222222222"|"Tyler"|"Ward"|"email328@yahoo.com"|"2022/08/23"|"UG"|"TR"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"2"|"1"|"RD"|"0"|"1"|"2023-03-09"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output from your posted sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did't show the expected output in your question so I don't know if this is correct or not but it implements what you described best I can tell:

```
$ awk -F'|' '(NR > 1) && ($11 ~ "/")' file
"30"|"958433018"|"999999999"|"11111111"|"202340"|""|"222222222"|"Tyler"|"Ward"|"email328@yahoo.com"|"2022/09/10"|"UG"|"TR"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"2"|"1"|"RD"|"0"|"1"|"2023-03-09"
"30"|"958433018"|"999999999"|"11111111"|"202340"|""|"222222222"|"Tyler"|"Ward"|"email328@yahoo.com"|"2022/08/23"|"UG"|"TR"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"2"|"1"|"RD"|"0"|"1"|"2023-03-09"
```

Comment: Another Question let's say that the date at the end also needs the same validation. meaning if the $11 OR  the last column had a slash in it.  Would it be something like this: awk -F'|' '(NR > 1) && ($11 ~ "/" || $Colnum ~ "/")' file

Comment: If you have another question then ask a new question, don't ask additional questions in comments as [Chameleon Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain who you provoked

```
  awk: cmd. line:1: {if(NR > 1) {{$11~/^//}}}
   awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ syntax error
```

You must not just use `/` inside `/`-delimited regular expression - this will confuse GNU `AWK`. You should either use escaped `/` i.e. `/` prefixed with `\`, so in order to output all lines with `/` one might do

```
awk '/\//' file.txt
```

alternatively, if you find such pile of slashes perplexing you might go octal (see [`\nnn` chapter in Escape Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html)) and do

```
awk '/\057/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go beyond detecting slashes, but replace them:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} {gsub("/", "-", $11)} 1' file
```

Assuming the date format is still Ymd